# Why cname appengine app always redirect to www.google.com?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a appengine app and google app account.

I have CNAME the domain name to the appengine app successful two months ago.

I find that CNAME fail to direct to the appengine app now, but the appengine app is OK. 
It always direct to Google site. Does everyone meet this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the instructions for adding the app to your google apps url listed here: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/domains.html

If so, you should double check that someone didn't change the app/url mapping.